# Import Swift Packages in Visual Studio Code

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code, swift-package-manager, swift-package

Im new with Swift and its tools.  I use this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sswg.swift-lang).
I added a [package](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to dependencies but when I try to import my package

```
import SwiftyJSON
```

terminal gives me an error:

```
error: no such module 'SwiftyJSON'
import SwiftyJSON
       ^
```

My `Package.swift` file:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "swiftpackages",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git", from: "4.0.0"),
    ]
)
```

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Try running `swift package update` from the same directory where your `Package.swift` file is located.

Comment: You should replace `SwiftyJson` by the native `JsonDecoder`. It is so much more useful (and so much more swifty :-).

Comment: @Patru It's all about process and not about exactly this package, I just wanna learn how to add packages in VS Code :)

Comment: @VadimBelyaev I already tried to update the package and it's up-to-date. I think there is a problem in VS Code

Comment: How is your code structured, how many modules do you have? Are you importing SwiftyJson in the file that is a part of the same package or from a different package?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev There is no code yet. I just wanna import this package as module for the next use.
I have 2 files: `Package.swfit` with my package and `testSwiftPackages.swift` where I import this module. It's my main file. No other modules/packages